# Agregar numero sobre carrito de compras en css

Tags: html, css

Necesito agregar un `badge` con la cantidad de productos que tengo en un shopping cart, no puedo lograr que este quede alineado correctamente, ni que el texto los iconos no se superponga entre si.

Algún conocedor de `CSS` que me pueda brindar una mano? busqué ejemplos pero no pude aplicar ninguno a mi situación.

```css
.sidebar-social li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 31.9%;
  margin-bottom: 3px!important;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #444444;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social a span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-menu align-items-center d-flex">
  <div class="sidebar-social">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i><span>Login</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span>Registrate</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Carrito</span></a>
        <span id="cart_menu_num" data-action="cart-can" class="badge rounded-circle">5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Así es como queda:

[image]

Como se puede ver, el `badge` queda lejos del carrito en lugar de quedar en su posición.

Y así escomo debería quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para posicionar el badge al lado de carrito tienes que usar las propiedades de posicionamiento que ofrece CSS. Aquí puedes aprender [sobre ello](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

He añadido posicionamiento `absolute` al badge y lo he puesto dentro del elemento padre (`<a>`) que contiene el icono del carrito. Al padre se le tiene que indicar el posicionamiento `relative`.

```css
.sidebar-social li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 31.9%;
  margin-bottom: 3px !important;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #444444;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social a span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* CSS para posicionar el bade cerca del carrito*/
.cart {
  position: relative;
}

#cart_menu_num {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 55%;
  background: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cart-menu align-items-center d-flex">
  <div class="sidebar-social">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i><span>Login</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span>Registrate</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="URL-HERE" class="cart" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><span>Carrito</span>
          <span id="cart_menu_num" data-action="cart-can" class="badge rounded-circle">5</span>
        </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quedo Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Lucas.Fradusco de nada. En tu código quita esto que `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cart-menu align-items-center d-flex">` para no añadir los iconos otra vez que he añadido yo para la demo.